# Communications link failure :Hibernate & Spring application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I tried suggested thing in other question of **Stackoverflow** and made changes in connection like below

```
<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/ccc?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8" />
        <property name="user" value="userName" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="30" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="240" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />


    </bean>
```

But still my project throwing

> SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 852,106
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   31,248 milliseconds ago.  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3715)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3604)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4155)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getPassword(JDBCRealm.java:547)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:406)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.doLogin(AuthenticatorBase.java:848)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.login(AuthenticatorBase.java:830)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2637)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1064)
>     at com.ccc.web.view.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:283)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)   at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv
>   failed    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:112)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:159)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:187)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3158)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3615)  ... 61
>   more

Anyone can tell me what is best way to overcome this issue?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at newer connection pools, like Tomcat connection pool or HikariCP

Comment: I did not get you can you elaborate little more?

Comment: You are using the `c3p0` connection pool, which is old and has a reputation of being a little difficult to work with. I haven't worked with `c3p0` myself so I don't have any suggestions on how to fix your `c3p0` connection problems, but I suggest that you take a look at the other connections pools that I mentioned

Comment: I am checking HikarCP but searching how to configure it in applicationcontext.xml file

Comment: Good choice! Check out these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172643/how-to-set-up-datasource-with-spring-for-hikaricp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630123/how-to-configure-datasource-with-hikaricp-in-spring-configuration-class

Comment: Do i need to define bean class also only datasource would not work?

Comment: Ultimately you'll need to create a datasource bean that is of type `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`. On way to do that is to pass a bean of type `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig` as a constructor argument

Comment: As in C3P0 i did not create any class is this possible Hikari will manage it like  C3P0 doing?

Comment: With `c3p0` you created a bean of type `ComboPooledDataSource`. You need to do the same thing for Hikari

Comment: Can you tell me best configuration properties of *Hikari* for a Web application running in production server? Also which will resolve above issue? Please write in answer section i will want to use hikari in production server as well.

Comment: I haven't used Hikari in anything but pet projects so I can't tell what the most reliable configuration would be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have done this with [hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">

        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/cc?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8</prop>
                <prop key="user">username</prop>
                <prop key="password">password</prop>
                <prop key="useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="characterEncoding">utf-8</prop>
                <prop key="cachePrepStmts">true</prop>
                <prop key="prepStmtCacheSize">250</prop>
                <prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</prop>
                <prop key="useServerPrepStmts">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="DataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case, its because the version of mysql server. The spring proyecto had configuration for mysql server 5.7 but in my computer had the version 8.