# Hikari Connection Pooling with eclipselink as a JPA provider : Spring + Eclipselink + HikariCP

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink, hikaricp

How to implement Hikari Connection Pooling with eclipselink as a JPA provider? I have tried to implement Hikari connection pooling at Tomcat level by adding HikariCP.jar and slf4j-api.jar in lib folder of Tomcat and adding following lines in server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DS_RW" auth="Container" 
                  factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  minimumIdle="5" 
                  maximumPoolSize="10"
                  connectionTimeout="300000"
                  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                  jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@domain.com:1545/service1"
                  dataSource.implicitCachingEnabled="true" 
                  username="username" 
                  password="password" 
                  accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" />
```

but my requirement is to create hikari connection pooling at application level instead of server level.

How to implement Hikari connection pooling in eclipselink as a JPA provider with spring framework ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630123/how-to-configure-datasource-with-hikaricp-in-spring-configuration-class

Comment: @user7294900 This question doesn't include eclipselink specific implementation